# TypeOrm querybuilder join relations and get only one column of the joined table

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

Let's say i have a ManyToOne relation of Carts and Users.
(it should be OneToOne but i intentionally make this manytoone for other reasons not important now)
So i would like to query using queryBuilder all the carts assigned to that user from my DB.

In my example the code is like that:

```
.createQueryBuilder('cart')
            .leftJoinAndSelect('cart.wetsuit', 'wetsuit')
            .leftJoinAndSelect('cart.board', 'board')
            .leftJoinAndSelect('cart.user', 'user')
            .where('user.uuid = :userUuid', {userUuid})
            .getMany()
```

But doing so i get returned the whole User Object. I would like to return only the user Email. How can i do that?